# How to update database through CSV for some columns

Tags: java, database, postgresql, spring-boot, csv

i have table in which there are columns like id, link_name ,browser_title ,title ,content etc..

which contain the relevant information
now i have the file  CSV which contains new title and browser_title values for some link
_names( CSV  looks like -- link_name, title, browser_title) now i have to update the values for title and browser_title .

can anyone suggest what should be the good way to do that

Comment: First you import the csv data into a temporary table with `COPY`, then you `UPDATE` your table from the temporary table.

Answer (score 1):

The task aims to replace certain data in a database table with corresponding values in a CSV file. To use Java directly for doing this requires loading the CSV file to the database and store it as a temporary table. That’s a hassle.

It is easy to do this using Java’s open-source package SPL. You just need one line of code:

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | =RDB.update@u(file("update_info.csv").import@ct(),infotable,link_name,title,browser_title) |

SPL offers JDBC driver to be invoked by Java. Just store the above SPL script as update.splx and invoke it in Java as you call a stored procedure:

```
…

Class.forName("com.esproc.jdbc.InternalDriver");

con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:esproc:local://");

st = con.prepareCall("call update ()");

st.execute();

…
```

Or execute the SPL string within a Java program as we execute a SQL statement:

```
…

st = con.prepareStatement("==RDB.update@u(file(\"update_info.csv\").import@ct(),
infotable,link_name,title,browser_title)");

st.execute();

…
```

View [SPL source code.](https://github.com/SPLWare/esProc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Using BufferedReader to read file and loop every line then every column.

```
String path = "file.csv";
String line = "";
String splitBy = ",";
try {
    // parsing a CSV file into BufferedReader
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path));
    // read file line by line
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) // returns a Boolean value
    {
        // spilt column values by comma
        String[] row = line.split(splitBy); // use comma as separator
        // print every column value
        for (int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
            System.out.println(row[i]);
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I modified a bit from this web site: https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-read-csv-file-in-java